# Trying to build a sequence of logical statements ||

Tags: function-construction, programming

I need to build a sequence of n conditions separated by ||. 
Something like,

f =  #1===f1[#2] || #1===f2[#2] || ... || #1===fn[#2] &

where the number n (integer, of course) is not fixed.

How can I do this?

I have tried with List and changing the Head but the trouble is that SameQ evaluates things too soon. The & at the end is apparently crucial.

Answer (score 5):

Reference [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
fList = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5};

Or @@@ Replace[Evaluate[fList] &, f_ :> # === f@#2, {2}]
```

> ```
> #1 === f1[#2] || #1 === f2[#2] || #1 === f3[#2] || #1 === f4[#2] || #1 === f5[#2] &
> ```

Similar:

```
Replace[Function @@ {Or @@ fList}, f_ :> # === f@#2, {2}]

make[{x__}] := Replace[Or[x] &, f_ :> # === f@#2, {2}]
make[fList]
```

---

### Modified approach

Inspired by WReach, if we may approach this flexibly we could simply write:

```
a === #[b] & /@ Or @@ fList
```

e.g.

```
1 === #[0] & /@ Or @@ {Sin, Cos, Tan}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Because `Or` is applied first this only evaluates functions until a match is found.  I think this pattern is simple enough to use as-is, but we can of course package it if desired:

```
test[{fns__}][a_, b_] := a === #@b & /@ Or[fns]

test[{Sin, Cos, Tan}][1, 0]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  Very useful

Answer (score 4):

Some `Hold[]` trickery can be used for this:

```
fList = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5};

Hold[Function][Or @@ Thread[Hold[SameQ][#1, Through[fList[#2]]]]] // ReleaseHold
   #1 === f1[#2] || #1 === f2[#2] || #1 === f3[#2] || #1 === f4[#2] || #1 === f5[#2] &
```

Answer (score 4):

If the application does not demand explicit use of code generation and `Or` then we might consider something like this:

```
test[fns___][x_, y_] := AnyTrue[{fns}, x === #[y] &]
```

This would allow us to define functions that test against any number of target functions.  For example:

```
f = test[Sin, Cos, Tan];
```

or equivalently:

```
f = test @@ {Sin, Cos, Tan};
```

`f` could then be used like this:

```
f[0, Pi/2]
(* True *)

f[1, Pi/2]
(* True *)

f[ComplexInfinity, Pi/2]
(* True *)

f[10, Pi/2]
(* False *)
```